# Local equality of functions implies global equality?

Tags: real-analysis, cv.complex-variables, power-series, counterexamples

The following question arised in my research, and I was unable to settle it after playing with it for sometime. Let $\{a^k_i\}_{i\geq 1}$  (for $k\in \{1,2,3,4\}$) be four sequences of real numbers. For each $k\in \{1,2,3,4\}$, consider the function $f_k:]-r_k,r_k[\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $x\mapsto\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_i^kx^i$ (Where $r_k$ is defined as $\frac{1}{\limsup_{i\rightarrow \infty}|a_i^k|^{\frac{1}{i}}}$).

It is given that for all $x$ sufficiently close to $0$, we have $f_2(f_1(x))=f_4(f_3(x))$.  It is also given that for some $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$, we have that both $f_2(f_1(x_0)), f_4(f_3(x_0))$ exist.  Must $f_2(f_1(x_0))= f_4(f_3(x_0))$  ? I would be very grateful if you can help, thank you.

**Edit:** "$f_2(f_1(x_0))$ exists" means that $x_0$ belongs to domain of $f_1$ and that $f_1(x_0)$belongs to domain of $f_2$. Similarly, "$f_4(f_3(x_0))$ exists" means that $x_0$ belongs to domain of $f_3$ and that $f_3(x_0)$belongs to domain of $f_4$

I know that the answer is yes in some special cases like $f_1$ equals identity map, or $f_1,f_2,f_3,f_4$ are rational functions (Which raises the question what if the $f_k$(s) are algebraic functions ?). I also considered extending the domain of the $f_k$(s) to an open subset of the complex plane and possibly open the route for analytic continuations and complex analysis machinery but was not successful with that.

Comment: @ThomasKojar I can do that locally around 0. Do I understand your question correctly?

Comment: @ThomasKojar But the bump function does not come from a power series or the composition of two power serieses , or does it ?

Comment: @ThomasKojar I am not convinced, perhaps I am missing something too obvious.  I don't think this will work since I require the function $f_k$ to be defined only on the the interval whose radius is the radius of convergence of the power series

Comment: You should be more specific about the exact meaning of the condition that $f_1(f_2(x_0)))$ and $f_4(f_3(x_0)))$ exist.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko I edited my question to clarify that. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @Amr Your question appears to be answered in the affirmative by two theorems:  that the composition of real-analytic functions is again real-analytic, and by the identity theorem for real-analytic functions.  Please look these theorems up and see if they answer your question.  If not, post an edit which makes your question more precise and addresses exactly why these two theorems do not solve your problem.

Comment: @StevenGubkin the set of points where $f_2\circ f_1,f_4\circ f_3$ (i.e. $f_1^{-1}(dom(f_2))\cap f_3^{-1}(dom(f_4)) $) are both defined need not be connected to apply the identity theorem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider $$\eqalign{f_1(x) &= (x+1)^2-1\cr f_2(x) &= \sqrt{x+1}-1\cr f_3(x) &= f_4(x) = x
}$$
$f_1, f_3$ and $f_4$ being polynomials, their radius of convergence is $\infty$, while $f_2(x)$ has a Maclaurin series with radius of convergence $1$.  $f_2(f_1(x)) = f_4(f_3(x)) = x$ for $x \in (-1,1)$.  But since $f_1(x) = f_1(-x-2)$, $f_2(f_1(x))$ is also defined for $x \in (-3,-1)$, with $f_2(f_1(x)) = -2-x$ there while $f_4(f_3(x)) = x$.

Comment: Thank you a lot. I unfortunately didnt ask a good question, for some reason I conviced myself that if one of $f_k$(s) are identity maps then there we are safe from finding a counterexample