# Composition of power series is power series?

Tags: power-series, counterexamples

$\DeclareMathOperator\dom{dom}$Sorry to bother the community again with these type of questions about power series, I am ready to delete the question if it is not suitable.

**Definition:** I say a function $h$ is $(m,n)$-representable by power series iff $0\in \dom(h)$, $h(0)=0$, and $h$ is a restriction (to a smaller domain) of some power series (centered at $0$) that takes as input $m$ real variables and outputs a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$. In other words, $0\in \dom(h)\subseteq B_r(0)$ (where $r$ is the radius of convergence of the power series), and for every $x\in \dom(h)$ we have that $h(x)$ equals the evaluation of the power series at the point $x$.

**Question:** Let $f$ be $(a,b)$-representable by power series. Let $g$ be $(b,c)$-representable by power series. It is given that $\dom(g\circ f)$ (i.e. $\{x\in \dom(f)\mid f(x)\in \dom(g)\}$) is path connected. It is also given that $\dom(f),\dom(g)$ are path connected. Must $g\circ f$ be $(a,c)$ representable by power series?

I edited my question to include the hypothesis of path connectivity of domains of $f,g$

Comment: Does the fact its multi variable make this considerably harder to prove than the usual result “composition of analytic functions is analytic”? I would try to look that result up and generalize it: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1345778/proof-composition-of-analytic-functions-is-analytic

Comment: @SidharthGhoshal The challenge is not about the multivariable part, but rather that I start from stronger hypotheses and want to reach stronger conclusions. Representability by power series is a stronger condition than just analyticity

Comment: Ah I see, let me think about this more. I didn’t recognize that subtlety

Comment: @SidharthGhoshal I am also interested about the multivariable part, but I think the main challenge is that I want to reach a stronger conclusion from stronger hypotheses.

Comment: Are also assuming these power series are not both around 0?

Comment: @SidharthGhoshal No, both are defined at $0$ as by the defintion of $(m,n)$ representablity by power series of my post. I edited my post to make sure that is clear

Comment: Okay but that means that something like $f = a_0 + a_1(x-1) + a_2(x-1)^2 + ... $ is (1,1) representable as long as $a_0 - a_1 + a_2 - a_3 ... = 0$ is well defined and converges to 0.

Comment: @SidharthGhoshal The power series in are all cenetered at $0$. I should have included that explicitly in my question. Sorry for that.

Comment: Doesn't substitution of power series correspond to composition of representable functions?

Comment: @Lspice Dear Lspice, thank you for your help. This was my inital intution, but now I am dubious about it. Please see this post https://mathoverflow.net/questions/449580/local-equality-of-functions-implies-global-equality/449608#449608

Comment: @arm: so, in other words, you are asking if the domain of convergence of the power series of $g \circ f$ is at least as big as that of $f$ or if it has shrunk after post-composition?

Comment: @M.G. I don't think your question is equivalent to my question. For example, if $f$ is identity, and $g$ is some power series with finite radius of convergence. Then we will have that $g\circ f$ is representalbe by power series , even though the radius of convergence of $g\circ f$ is not as big as the radius of convergence of $f$

Comment: @Amr: ah, right, I see. Let me check if I've understood it this time. You are asking whether the domain of convergence of the power series of $g \circ f$ is at least as big as $f^{-1}(dom(g))$, which is the domain of definition of the *function* $g \circ f$. Correct?

Comment: @M.G. Yes. The answer to that question is no in general (i.e. without connectivity of $g^{-1}(dom(f))$) as can be seen from this post https://mathoverflow.net/questions/449580/local-equality-of-functions-implies-global-equality/449608#449608.

Comment: @Amr: Ok, so then it seems that this depends on how small of a restriction of a power series the function $g$ is, i.e. if you take $g$ to be a restriction to a very small open neighbourhood $N$, then $f^{-1}(N)$ can get small enough to fit within the domain of convergence of the power series of $g \circ f$. I guess the question is then if (and when) this breaks.

Comment: @M.G. I would state what you stated  slightly different . If $N$ is small enough so that $f^{-1}(N)$  is connected, does that necessarily mean that $f^{-1}(N)$ is small enough to fit inside the domain of convergence of the power series of $g\circ f$ ?

Comment: It is usually not appropriate to edit your post just to do something like add "(question still unsolved)" to the title.  A user viewing a post summary that includes your post will see that it has an answer, but also that that answer has not been accepted, and so will know that you do not regard the question as solved.  I have edited out the parenthesis.

Comment: @LSpice Sorry for that.  It is just that there is one answer that has a flawed argument that one can manipulate infinite sums as finite sums, and so it does not answer the question. I thought perhaps mathematicians here will not both to open the link to a question with an elementary title that already has an answer. Can we delete the answer in this post , since it already admits to being wrong and does not add anything useful whatsoever ?

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1162637), no, except in extreme cases deleting an answer is up to the answerer, and is not necessarily appropriate even if they agree (it can be useful to see approaches that have been tried but didn't work). Again, everyone sees, even before opening your question, that, although it has an answer, the answer has not been accepted; and anyone who clicks through will see @SidharthGhoshal's prominent warning that their answer is wrong.  But, knowing all that, if you feel that the parenthesis in the title is essential, you are free to roll back my edit.

Comment: @LSpice Okay. Thanks for your feedback

Comment: I’ll delete it :)

Comment: @SidharthGhoshal Thanks, I appreciate it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe I misunderstood the question, is this a counterexample?

Let $c>1$, put $f(x) = \sin x$ and $g(x) = \tfrac{x}{c^2+x^2}$. Then $f$ is representable by a power series on $\mathbb{R}$, $g$ is representable by a power series on $(-c,c)$ and $f(\mathbb{R}) \subset (-c,c)$.

However, the meromorphic function $g \circ f$ has a pole at $i \sinh^{-1}(c)$, so the power series of $g \circ f$ is only convergent on $(- \sinh^{-1}(c), \sinh^{-1}(c))$, not on all of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Yes this is a counterexample. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Dear Prof. David, Will the situation changed if I had changed the hypothesis and required my power series(es) to be be power series in a complex variable instead of a power series in a real variable ?